# Split a string without delimiter C

Tags: c, string, split

I have a string of 256 characters and I would like to split it in 64 strings of 4 characters in c, but I do not have delimiters, is there any function to do so?

I have the following code:

```
char message[256]="MSN0MSN1MSN2MSN3..";
char a[4];

for(i=0;i<64;i++)
{
   memcpy(a[i],message+(i*4),4);
   *(ram_tx+i)=a(i);
}
```

the part of the ram_tx works, the problem in the code is the memcpy as when I printf the a[I] it shows:

MSN0
MSN1
MSN23

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You'll need to roll your own. Out of interest, why can't you just treat the original string as 64 strings of 4 characters, when you are indexing into it?

Comment: I have a ram memory that is 64x4 matrix and I put put all the message inside

Comment: loop with `memcpy`. That should do it.

Comment: Are you really talking about "strings", or just arrays of characters.

Comment: you _have_ a separator: the 64 byte size. Try something, it's not very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem with just cut your string in 64 ?

```
#define NB_STRING 64
#define STRING_LEN 4

int main(void)
{
    char input[256] = "... something";
    char output[NB_STRING][STRING_LEN + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_STRING; ++i) {
        memcpy(output[i], input + (i * STRING_LEN), STRING_LEN);
        output[i][STRING_LEN] = '\0';
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_STRING; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", output[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

---

---

Edit after the OP inserted the following code :

```
char message[256]="MSN0MSN1MSN2MSN3..";
char a[4];

for(i=0;i<64;i++)
{
   memcpy(a[i],message+(i*4),4);
   *(ram_tx+i)=a(i);
}
```

Well, it will indeed probably not work, first because we do not know what "ram_tx" is (his type, notably), and because the code is highly suspicious.

You declare a as "char [4]" and then you do "a(1)". You understand that here, you call a **function** nammed "a" with the parameter "1" ? And even if you correct this by either put "a[1]" or just "a" in order to copy the array in ram_tx, well, it seem alway suspicious, even if ram_tx is an pointer array (because what is the point of having all your pointer point to a ?).

Understand that at each for loop, you will erase the previous value of "a".
Is "ram_tx" reponsible for the display ? If yes, can you add a delimitator in order to know what "a" really contain ?
Futhermore, is "ram_tx" waiting an '\0' ? Because you don't add it, and it's probably what "add" some garbage value that you don't want.

Comment: yeah but we don't know if OP is talking about nul terminated strings or just byte strings.

Comment: also, when posting code out of the blue, it better be _really_ good code.

Comment: it happens when the question is too broad :)

Comment: The only problem with the code is that if the string is not 256 char length, il will "split" garbage value. But the question is clear : the input string is 256 char in length.

Comment: This code covers both the 'null terminated string' and the 'byte string' cases — it just wastes 1 byte per string if they're byte strings.  If the platform has problems because of 64 bytes being used that it couldn't afford to waste, it is unusual these days

Comment: The problem is that when I try to copy it it copy it randomly not in order being it input="MSG1MSG2MSG3.." and output ="MSG1,MSG1,MSG2;MSG1"

Comment: You will have to provide a code that we can test, because it's probably not normal at all. Can you edit your question with your code ? And as  user3386109 asked already, is there "string" (nul-terminated) or array of char ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please provide us with wath "ram_tx" is, because even if you say "it's not the problem", for me it seem that it is the problem !